# How do I disable xcode debug tab?

Tags: ios, xcode

Everytime I close my iOS app in the emulator, a tab called AppDelegate pops out, I find this annoying, how do I disable it?

Comment: Are you completely sure about **Apple**Delegate?

Comment: I guess it's because you kill the app and Xcode shows from where that happened. Do you have exception breakpoints on?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake, the tab's name is AppDelegate, and no i don't have any exception breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn off the “Debug Executable” checkbox in your scheme—then Xcode won't debug your app at all. Probably not what you want.

Instead of quitting your app in the simulator, click the Stop button (the square) in the Xcode toolbar. This tells Xcode to kill your app, and it will automatically detach the debugger.

Comment: Thanks! I will use the Stop button instead.

Comment: You can also press ⌘-period (when Xcode is the front app) instead of clicking the stop button.